# How I can dynamically change font in Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt

I have qt 5.5 application with a lot of widgets. Each widget has self font family for draw text. Some of them defined in QSS file, some set directly to QPainter.

Application has localization for some languages. For one of language I should change font family for all widget dynamically (all widgets should have one font family) and revert changes for other languages.

Comment: How about QApplication::setFont? Maybe application restart may be required. Otherwise — with stylesheets.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `QApplication::setFont()` to set a default font for multiple widgets at once, you can either use it to set the default font for everything, or to set it for a specific widget class, if you pass the class as a secont parameter. Note that this can *not* be used at the same time with stylesheets.

If you want to set the default font for one specific widget, you can use that widget's `setFont()` function as well. Note that if the widget that you are setting font for also have a stylesheet attached, in a case of conflicting properties the values from the stylesheet will be used.